# Apache 2.4.6 - Sending GZIP content SOMETIMES results in "read more bytes of request body than expected"

Tags: android, apache, http, gzip, content-length

We are trying to send GZIPed content to you web application which is hosted on a Tomcat behind an Apache 2 via mod_proxy's ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives. Most of the time this works but sometimes the Apache rejects these packages and we get the following errors in our Apache error logs:

```
[proxy_http:error] ... AH01086: read more bytes of request body than expected (got 16384, expected 1562)  
[proxy_http:error] ... AH01097: pass request body failed to x.x.x.x:8080 (x.x.x.x) from x (x.x.x.x)
```

The code sending the data is based on the HttpsURLConnection and executed from an Android device. It looks something like this:

```
URL url = new URL(Constants.URL);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MyApp 1.0");

OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write( zipStringToBytes("Some possibly long content.") );

outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

And this the function the create our GZIP String:

```
private static byte[] zipStringToBytes(String input) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //use PrintStream to avod converting a String into byte array, that can cause out of memory error
    final PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new GZIPOutputStream(bos));
    printStream.print(input);
    printStream.close();

    byte[] retval = bos.toByteArray();
    bos.close();
    return retval;
}
```

We have not been able to figure out the reason for this yet. Especially since it seems to occur sporadically. This makes us think it might be a problem with the Content-Length, or our code sending the data in general, but we don't know and cannot find and related issues. If you have any pointers on this, we would greatly appreciate it.

If you need more information, please let me know.

**Update:**
What we found is, that the expected size is always the same: **16384** but  the expected size varies. Maybe this helps.

**Update 2:**
We have currently disabled chunked mode:
     con.setChunkedStreamingMode ( 0 )
This seems to help. Can anyone maybe explain if this is a solution and why it is one. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but don't have control of the client side code. If anyone knows a server side solution (i.e. an apache setting) I would be much obliged.

Comment: Are you using `http` or `ajp` for Tomcat connection? Do you use mod_proxy_balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for now we were able to solve the issue by disabling sending data in chunked mode.

```
con.setChunkedStreamingMode ( 0 )
```

While we have some ideas why this solves the issue, we have not come up with an in depth explanation.

As long as nobody has a better solution or explanation, I accept this solution.